# Android Studio Emulator Random Restart?

Tags: android-emulator

My Android Studio Emulator randomly restarts while using. Is this some kind of bug or is it could be a setting problem on my system? I have checked the settings it doesn't seem anything might be linked to this and I haven't seen anything reported regarding this?